# Python generate tree based on browsing patterns

Tags: python, tree

I have some browsing patterns of users like following separated by '/'. What is the easiest way to generate a tree using python.

```
A/B
A/C
A/C/D
A/C/E
F/G
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want a "graph" library, like one of these:

http://graph-tool.skewed.de/

https://code.google.com/p/python-graph/

Comment: Hey Thanks, I'll look in to them :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to build up a structure by urls, better start with such a class

```
class Node(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.children = {}

    def insert(self, paths):
        child_name = paths.pop(0)
        if not child_name in self.children:
            self.children[child_name] = Node(child_name)
        if paths:
            self.children[child_name].insert(paths)
```

And this is how to use it.

```
with open('urls.txt') as urls:
    root = Node('')
    for url in urls:
        root.insert(url.split('/'))
```